# MyDrawPanel and JPanel interference

Tags: java

How would I have a MyDrawPanel AND a JPanel in the same frame without them interfering each other? 
When I add a JPanel to the JFrame which already contains a MyDrawPanel, the KeyListener  on the MyDrawPanel  stops catching the events, although MouseListener and actions on the JPanel perform correctly. After some research I figured that it needs to be focused on in order to receive the KeyListener events, but I couldnt find and exact answer on how to do it. 
So what do I need to do?

Comment: I'm not sure what you actually want, but I feel utilizing the glass pane is what you might need: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html

Comment: A JFrame has a [BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) as its default.  Put your drawing panel in the center, and your other JPanel somewhere else.  A JPanel with Swing components like JButtons will have focus over a drawing panel.  Instead of using a key listener, use [key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).